# How to format inconsistent email fonts in Contact Form 7?

Tags: css, fonts, html-email, inline, contact-form-7

I have a simple Contact Form 7 form that works great. I have it set to HTML and have some simple formatting where I set the p tags to Arial, and some bold.

All the bold is fine. And most of the text is set to Arial. However, if the  of the message has multiple lines, they revert back to Times New Roman on subsequent lines.

What is the right way to ensure the entire email (which is just a few p tags) is consistently set to the right font family? Should I wrap it all in a span? Div? HTML email formatting is always a bit of a mystery.

Example:

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
<b>To Department:</b> [_raw_department]
<b>From:</b> [your-name] <[your-email]>
<b>Company:</b> [corporate-name]
<b>Phone:</b> [phone]
</p>

<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
<b>Message Body:</b>
[your-message]
</p>

<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
-- 
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on ABC123 (http://www.abc123.com)
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a paragraph tag which has the font decleration:

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
```

If you add a new parapragh it has to have the same font styling as the other paragraph tags for it to be uniform.

Try to use a table as an outer wrapper which has the font decleration, now regardless of how many paragraph tags you create your fonts will stay the same.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">

<p>
<b>To Department:</b> [_raw_department]
<b>From:</b> [your-name] <[your-email]>
<b>Company:</b> [corporate-name]
<b>Phone:</b> [phone]
</p>

<p>
<b>Message Body:</b>
[your-message]
</p>

<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
-- 
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on ABC123 (http://www.abc123.com)
</p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** Different email clients render paragraph margins differently. If you are using paragraphs, please use it as:

```
<p style="font-weight:normal;margin:0;Margin:0px;padding:0px;"></p>
```

This will ensure your paragraphs stay the same as line break or you can use break tags to simulate paragraph tags. Personally I use break tags to say away from extra codes.

Hope the above answers your question.